# PHP Array Matching

Tags: php, arrays

I'm semi-new to PHP and looking for a good way to match arrays. Note that I'm going to write my arrays here in python syntax because its way easier to type, but I'm working in PHP.

I have an array that is something like this: {3:4,5:2,6:2}

Then I have an array of arrays, with the inners arrays having the same basic form as the array above. I'd like to write a function that returns all arrays that match the given array, ignoring extra values.

So I want the array above to match {3:4,6:2,5:2} or {3:4,5:2,6:2,7:2}

but not {3:4,5:2} or {3:4,5:2,6:3}

I probably could get it to work, but I doubt the code would be all that great. So I'd love the opinion of better PHP developers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a pre-defined function in php that will help with this sort of thing.  Just loop through all the arrays and find the ones that match your criteria.

```
function query( $query, $arrayOfArrays) {

  $ret = array();
  foreach( $arrayOfArrays as $array) {
    if( matches( $array, $query) ) {
      $ret[] = $array;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

function matches( $array, $query) {
  foreach( $query as $key => $value) {
    if( !isset( $array[$key]) || $array[$key] != $value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this code, but changing the matches function to use the intersect function.

Answer (score 3):

you want array_intersect or array_intersect_key

```
$a = array(1 => 11, 3 => 33, 2 => 22);
$b = array(3 => 33, 5 => 55, 2 => 22, 1 => 11);

if (array_intersect_key($a, $b) == $a)
    echo "b contains a";
```

Comment: I'm always amazed at how many predefined functions there are in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP 5.3 then you can use a closure along with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
// array to test against
$test = array(
    3 => 4,
    5 => 2,
    6 => 2
);

// array of arrays you need to check
$subjects = array(
    array(3 => 4, 5 => 2, 6 => 2),
    array(3 => 4, 6 => 2, 5 => 2, 7 => 2),
    array(3 => 4, 5 => 2),
    array(3 => 4, 5 => 2, 6 => 3),
);

// make $test available within the filter function with use
$result = array_filter($subjects, function($subject) use ($test) 
{
    // making use of array_intersect_key
    // note that $subject must be the first parameter for this to work
    return array_intersect_key($subject, $test) == $test;
});
```

`$result` will contain only the matching arrays